# How to add a single item to a PagedList using RxJava

Tags: android, apollo, android-paging

My project is using Google's paging library to load some stuff into a RecyclerView. We use RxJava paired with an Apollo GraphQL query to get the data which works fine. However, we also setup a GraphQl subscription to get new items as they come in, one at a time. This works fine.

However, I am unable to find any ways to add a single new item to the pagedlist without totally reloading it. Is this even possible? We'd like to avoid having to refresh the whole list each time a new item comes through and are trying to determine if we should stick with this paging library, or do something else. Unfortunately all documentation and other SO answers I've found haven't helped. Any advice or help would be much appreciated!